# Transfering files through github API

Tags: github-api, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer files using the GitHub API by curl. The files may have any extension (eg: .java, .jar, .jpg, etc). I have found no solutions in the net. Is there a way I can do this? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by transfer file?

there is an option of uploading a blob files through the github api `/repos/git/blobs`.
you should add a parameter of the content of the file in `base64` format.
if you want to use them later on you can create new `tree` with the returned `SHA`.

base64 online converter: https://www.base64decode.org/